# Angular - Reactive form - FormArray

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to implement add multiple lines using Angular Reactive - FormArray.

In the example I have 2 text fields. After entering the data and click the add button I want to add it to the lines.

After adding I am not able to clear the data entry 2 text fields.
And the last added element in the array is still linked to data entry.

Is FormArray suitable in this case, or should I use a simple approach please

Here is my code.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/jay-angular-reactive-array-mwhmcn

Answer (score 1):

I did not get what are trying to do with `FormArray`, thus I suggest a simpler way to achieve what you want.

Change your TS to:

```
export class AppComponent  {

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }
  public simpleArray = [];
  form: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {

    this.form = this.fb.group({
      country1: ['', Validators.required],
      service1: ['', Validators.required]
    });

  }

  add() {
    this.simpleArray.push(this.form.value);
    //this.form.reset();
    this.form.get('country1').setValue('');
    this.form.get('service1').setValue('');
  }


  deleteService(i) {
    this.simpleArray.splice(i,1)
  }
}
```

And your HTML should be :

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
   <h3>Angular Reactive form -  FormArray Demo </h3>
   Form : {{ simpleArray | json}}
   <br/><br/>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="country">Country</label>
      <input required type="text" id="country" class="form-control" formControlName="country1" />
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="service">Serivce</label>
      <input required type="text" id="service" class="form-control" formControlName="service1" />
   </div>
   <br />
   <button type='button' class="btn btn-primary" (click)='add()'>Add Services</button>
   <br />
   <div >
      <div class='row' *ngFor="let line of simpleArray let i=index">             
         <input class='form-control col-md-2' [value]="line.country1" />
         <input class='form-control col-md-2' [value]="line.service1"/>
         <button class='btn btn-primary col-md-1' (click)="deleteService(i)">Delete</button>
      </div>
   </div>
   <br />
</form>
```

***[A working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/jay-angular-reactive-array-yz1oce?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)***